# How to connect Testlink to SQL Server 2012 instead of mysql

Tags: testlink

I am installing Test link on Windows 10. I  got the success in hosting testlink from IIS. I want to use SQL Server 2012 instead of mysql.

Does anybody have a suggestion how to connect to SQL Server instead of mysql?

Answer (score -1):

I am able to install testlink on windows and SQL Server

https://www.blogger.com/blogger.g?blogID=9113225591614812013#editor/target=post;postID=68942667794676245;onPublishedMenu=allposts;onClosedMenu=allposts;postNum=0;src=postname

Comment: Link doesn't work.